# SQLAlchemy - session returns values, cursor does not

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

Whenever I connect to my database with a session, it returns the expected values. However, cursor commands do not appear to return any values.

Here is my boilerplate:

```
import pprint, sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Event

database = 'sandbox_test'
engine = db.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass!!@localhost:3306/'+database+'?charset=utf8')
```

---

Here is my '**session**' block:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
results = session.query(Event).first()
pprint.pprint(results.emp_id)
```

It returns `firstname_lastname`.

---

Here is my '**cursor**' block:

```
conn = engine.raw_connection()
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('select * from events limit 100;',multi=True)
results = curs.fetchone()
pprint.pprint(results)
```

It returns `None`.

How have I formatted the cursor block incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the cursor, then iterate over that result, like this:

```py
conn = engine.raw_connection()
curs = conn.cursor()

for res in curs.execute("""SELECT * FROM test;SELECT * FROM test;""", multi=True):
    for row in res:
        print(row)
```

This is based on the MySQL Connector docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).  For raw connection actions you need to refer to the specific DB-API driver docs as the precise API and calling conventions tend to vary back driver and RDBMS.  The SQLAlchemy docs only provide general guidance in these cases.